# how to plot a k-distance graph in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

How do I plot (in python) the distance graph for a given value of min-points in DBSCAN???

I am looking for the knee and corresponding epsilon value.

In the sklearn I do not see any method that return such distances.... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use the matrix operations provided by numpy to speed up your distance matrix calculation.

```
def k_distances2(x, k):
    dim0 = x.shape[0]
    dim1 = x.shape[1]
    p=-2*x.dot(x.T)+np.sum(x**2, axis=1).T+ np.repeat(np.sum(x**2, axis=1),dim0,axis=0).reshape(dim0,dim0)
    p = np.sqrt(p)
    p.sort(axis=1)
    p=p[:,:k]
    pm= p.flatten()
    pm= np.sort(pm)
    return p, pm
m, m2= k_distances2(X, 2)
plt.plot(m2)
plt.ylabel("k-distances")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why dim1 is never used? Do you want to use reshape(dim0, dim1) instead of reshape(dim0, dim0)?

Answer (score 9):

First you can define a function to calculate the distance of each point to its k-th nearest neighbor:

```
def calculate_kn_distance(X,k):

    kn_distance = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        eucl_dist = []
        for j in range(len(X)):
            eucl_dist.append(
                math.sqrt(
                    ((X[i,0] - X[j,0]) ** 2) +
                    ((X[i,1] - X[j,1]) ** 2)))

        eucl_dist.sort()
        kn_distance.append(eucl_dist[k])

    return kn_distance
```

Then, once you have defined your function, you can choose a *k* value and plot the histogram to find a knee to define an appropriate *epsilon* value.

```
eps_dist = calculate_kn_distance(X[1],4)
plt.hist(eps_dist,bins=30)
plt.ylabel('n');
plt.xlabel('Epsilon distance');
```

[image]

In the example above, a vast majority of points lie within 0.12 units from their 4th nearest neighbor. So, a heuristic approach, could be choosing 0.12 as *epsilon* parameter.

Answer (score 4):

To get distances you could use this function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

def k_distances(X, n=None, dist_func=None):
    """Function to return array of k_distances.

    X - DataFrame matrix with observations
    n - number of neighbors that are included in returned distances (default number of attributes + 1)
    dist_func - function to count distance between observations in X (default euclidean function)
    """
    if type(X) is pd.DataFrame:
        X = X.values
    k=0
    if n == None:
        k=X.shape[1]+2
    else:
        k=n+1

    if dist_func == None:
        # euclidean distance square root of sum of squares of differences between attributes
        dist_func = lambda x, y: math.sqrt(
            np.sum(
                np.power(x-y, np.repeat(2,x.size))
            )
        )

    Distances = pd.DataFrame({
        "i": [i//10 for i in range(0, len(X)*len(X))],
        "j": [i%10 for i in range(0, len(X)*len(X))],
        "d": [dist_func(x,y) for x in X for y in X]
    })
    return np.sort([g[1].iloc[k].d for g in iter(Distances.groupby(by="i"))])
```

`X` should be `pandas.DataFrame` or `numpy.ndarray`. `n` is number of neighbors that are in d-neighborhood. You should know this number. By default is number of attributes + 1.

To plot those distances you could use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = k_distances(X,n,dist_func)
plt.plot(d)
plt.ylabel("k-distances")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll try my best to do an extensive guide for future viewers
In a nutshell the steps are (using [distance matrix](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Clustering/Distance%20Matrix.htm))

1. Get the sorted distance matrix
2. Get the kth column (kth column represents the distances with kth neighbour)
3. Sort the kth column in descending order
4. Plot it in y-axis and (0-n) in x-axis

Lets take a simple dataset with n = 7

```
   x,   y
1  1,   1
2  1.5, 1.5
3  1.25,1.25
4  1.5, 1
5  1,   1.5
6  1.75,1.75
7  3,   2
```

[image]

```
The sorted distance matrix
[[0, 0.353, 0.5,   0.5,   0.707, 1.061, 2.236]
 [0, 0.353, 0.353, 0.5,   0.5,   0.707, 1.581]
 [0, 0.353, 0.353, 0.353, 0.353, 0.707, 1.904]
 [0, 0.353, 0.5,   0.5,   0.707, 0.791, 1.803]
 [0, 0.353, 0.5,   0.5,   0.707, 0.791, 2.062]
 [0, 0.353, 0.707, 0.791, 0.791, 1.061, 1.275]
 [0, 1.273, 1.581, 1.803, 1.904, 2.062, 2.236]]  
 
 The sorted kth (k=4) Column (5th column)  
 [1.904,0.791,0.707,0.707,0.707,0.5,0.353]
```

Now plotting this will yield

```
plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[1.904,0.791,0.707,0.707,0.707,0.5,0.353])
```

[image]

As you can see there is a strong bend at 0.79. So for k/minpts = 4, any point which have kth neighbour distance > 0.79 will be considered noise/non-core point.

Of course there's no guarantee that there will be a strong bend or even a bend at all in the graph it completely depends on the distribution of data
[The original paper](https://file.biolab.si/papers/1996-DBSCAN-KDD.pdf)

Comment: Link dead, working alternative from aaai.org: https://new.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf

Comment: @FilippoVitale Chrome is showing not secure for some reasons, however I found another alternative https://file.biolab.si/papers/1996-DBSCAN-KDD.pdf